# Vim is spellchecking in XML files where I don't want it to, and only there

Tags: vim, xml, spell-check

I'm trying to use Vim's builtin spellchecking in some XML documents. This happens merely by having the XML syntax loaded, as seen in the following minimalistic example (which reproduces what I also see in large XML documents):

[image: spellchecking text but not xml]

Note that given two buffers with exactly the same content, when `Filetype` is `text`, the spellchecking works; when it is `xml`, it does not. `spell` is set in both buffers.

However, given this view of the top three lines of a large XML document, you can see that the spellchecking is certainly on:

[image: spellchecking working on attributes]

but it is only checking attributes.

The nuisance is that none of the things it is actually finding are mispelled, and it isn't finding any of the numerous misspellings in the document. I would like it at a minimum to find the spelling errors in the body of the document, and being able to turn off the checking on attributes would be a nice option.

I've searched for `@NoSpell` in the `xml.vim` file, but that returns no hits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9234925/834176) contains a partial answer, which turned on the spellchecking in main body of the document. I put this in the part of my autocommands that initializes my XML files:

```
set spell
syntax spell toplevel
let &spellfile=$HOME . "/.xml." . &encoding . ".add"
```

The first command ensures the spelling is on. The second is the partial fix; the third sets a file such as `/home/usr/.xml.utf-8.add` as a file to save words added to the spelling dictionary for UTF-8 XML files.

Because I've made this file specific to XML files, if I'm not afraid of making that `xsl` will represent an actual misspelling elsewhere in the document, I could add that to the dictionary, etc; and thus it could be a full answer.

However, I found a better way to turn off spellchecking on attributes: changing the `@Spell` associated with attributes in `xml.vim` to `@NoSpell` (these lines are near the top of the file):

```
syn region  xmlString contained start=+"+ end=+"+ contains=xmlEntity,@NoSpell display
syn region  xmlString contained start=+'+ end=+'+ contains=xmlEntity,@NoSpell display
```

Together, these two sets of commands provide a full solution.

[image: fixed]